# function without printing none

Tags: python-3.x

*for some reason I'm printing two `None`s, can someone explain how to avoid that?*

```
class Wizard():
    def __init__(self,name, gender,power):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender 
        self.power = power
    def fire(self):
        print('My power is the fire')
    def wind(self):
        print ('My power is the wind')
                
    
 def power_wizard(self):
     if power == 1:
         print(Wizard.fire(self))
     else:
         a=print(Wizard.wind(self))
    
    
# Create player
    
name = input('Enter your wizard name: ')
gender = input ('Enter the gender: ')
power = int(input ('Choose your power 1) Fire and 2) Wind:(only numbers)'))
    
    
    
player1 = Wizard(name,gender,power)
    
    
print(player1.name)
print(power_wizard(power))
```

*print (The question is how can I not print `None` or why am I printing `None`)*

```
My power is the fire
None
None
```

*And also why are 2 None where are the coming from, because when de function wizard_power there only to results.*

Comment: @axe319 : the last line (`print(power_wizard(power))`) indicates that `power_wizard` was a indeed a function and _not_ a Wizard method in his original code.

Comment: @GeorgesMartin I un indented it. the `self` led me to believe it was a formatting error. It will function this way, the argument name just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Axe319 yes, I know, it was a bit confusing at first. That’s why I re-constructed it step-by-step in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> why am I printing None

When you execute `print(power_wizard(power))`, the following happens:

- the `power_wizard()` function is called.

  - in that `power_wizard()` function, you call the `Wizard.fire()` or `Wizard.wind()` methods...

    - in both methods, you `print('My power is...')`...
    - ...but you don't return any result.
  - in the `power_wizard()` function, you `print` the result of the `Wizard.fire()` or `Wizard.wind()` methods but, as those methods returns nothing, **`None` is printed a first time**.
  - the `power_wizard()` function returns no results either...
- ...thus, the outermost `print(power_wizard(power))` **prints a second `None`**.

---

That said, your `Wizard` class and `power_wizard()` function are a bit tangled...

You could easily remove the `Wizard.fire()` and `Wizard.wind()` methods and the `power_wizard()` function and have:

```
class Wizard():
    def __init__(self, name, gender, power):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender 
        self.power = power

player1 = Wizard("Gandalf", "male", "fire")
player2 = Wizard("Hermione", "female", "wind")
player3 = Wizard("Draco", "male", "invisibility")

for p in (player1, player2, player3):
    print("My name is %s and I have %s power" % (p.name, p.power))

# My name is Gandalf and I have fire power
# My name is Hermione and I have wind power
# My name is Draco and I have invisibility power
```

If you want to restrict the list of Wizard powers:

```py
class Wizard():

    powers = ("fire", "wind")  # this is a _class variable_ defining
                               # all powers available to Wizards

    def __init__(self, name, gender, power):
        self.name = name
        self.gender = gender

        if power in Wizard.powers:
            self.power = power
        else:
            raise ValueError("%s is not a Wizard power." % (power))

player3 = Wizard("Draco", "male", "invisibility")
# ValueError: invisibility is not a Wizard power.
```

If you want to let wizards describe themselves:

```py
class Wizard():
    ...

    def __init__(self, name, gender, power):
        ...

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<% is a %s with %s power>" % (
            self.name, self.__class__.__name__, self.power)

for p in (player1, player2):
    print(p)

# <Gandalf is a Wizard with fire power>
# <Hermione is a Wizard with wind power>
```

Then, if you want to make a wizard interactively:

```
def make_wizard():
    while True:
        name = input("Enter your wizard name: ")
        if name:
            break

    gender = input("Enter its gender: ")

    choices = ", ".join(Wizard.powers)
    while True:
        power = input("Enter its power (%s): " % (choices))
        if power in Wizard.powers:
            break

    return Wizard(name, gender, power)

player1 = make_wizard()
print(player1)

# Enter your wizard name: 
# Enter your wizard name: Gandalf
# Enter its gender: male
# Enter its power (fire, wind): invisibility
# Enter its power (fire, wind): fire
# 
# <Gandalf is a Wizard with fire power>
```

If you want powers to be numbered choices:

```py
def make_wizard():
    ...

    choices = ", ".join("%i: %s" % (i, name) 
                        for i, name
                        in enumerate(Wizard.powers, start=1))
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input("Enter its power (%s): " % (choices)))
            # will raise ValueError if choice is not a int

            power = Wizard.powers[choice-1]
            # will raise IndexError if choice-1 is not 
            # in Wizard.powers range
        except ValueError, IndexError:
            continue
        else:
            break

    return Wizard(name, gender, power)

player1 = make_wizard()
print(player1)

# Enter your wizard name: 
# Enter your wizard name: Gandalf
# Enter its gender: male
# Enter its power (1: fire, 2: wind): invisibility
# Enter its power (1: fire, 2: wind): 3
# Enter its power (1: fire, 2: wind): 1
# 
# <Gandalf is a Wizard with fire power>
```

(that was fun... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can only run the print statement if its return is not None like this. Its a bandaid fix.

`if player1.name is not None:   print(player1.name)`

Comment: Check OP's question, this isn't a relevant answer